# Occasional Error "remote name could not be resolved" when calling asp.net webservice on same machine

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7

I have a Windows 2008 R2 IIS7 web server with a .Net 3.5 web application which communicates with a .Net 3.5 web service on the same machine over https. Occasionally (maybe once in two days) the web application receives an error "remote name could not be resolved '[machinename]'" when calling the web service. The web server is set up to recycle the application pool every night, the error occurs during normal business hours. I could not detect anything unusual in the logs, the worker process does not consume a lot of memory either.

Any ideas?

Note: The web application and the web service were originally on two different machines. I moved the web service to the web application's server when trying to identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue using the new .NET 4.0 HttpClient class randomly. Restarting the application causes it to work fine again. Very strange...